# Setting window size in ICAClient

Tags: multiple-monitors, icaclient

I installed `ICAClient`. When I remote login to office computer, window size is not proper and it does not support dual monitors.

I followed instuctions as per https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2117525

Now I get error message:

```
Lockdown requirements not satisfied (No value for (TWIMode) satisfies all lockdown requirements.
```

Below is the setting I changed in `~/.ICAClient/All_Regions.ini`

```
[Virtual Channels\Seamless Windows]
TWIMode=Off

[Virtual Channels\Thinwire Graphics]
DesiredHRES=1800
DesiredVRES=1080
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

a bit late but I had the same message today (one monitor only though).
I did a "locate All_Regions.ini" and changed all files to the same setting. Including the one in your ~/.ICAClient directory.

Comment: Please add  a clear answer to the question so any one can follow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set TWIMode=False in that file. I didn't need to change DesiredHRES or DesiredVRES from the default *